# How to add comma on preg_match like this

Tags: php

This is my sample preg_match and working, but how to add Comma "," on code already like bellow

```
$content = explode(" ",$title);
$result = "";

foreach($content as $value){
if(!preg_match("/\.|'/",$value)){
    $find = mysqli_query($db, "select * from table where column1='$value'");
    $j = mysqli_num_rows($find);
    if($j>0){
        $ka = mysqli_fetch_array($find);
        $result = $result.$ka['column2'];
    }else{
        $find2 = mysqli_query($db, "select * from table where column2='$value'");
        $j2 = mysqli_num_rows($find2);
        if($j2>0){
            $ka2 = mysqli_fetch_array($find2);
            $result = $result.$ka2['column1']);
        }else{
            $result = $result.$value;
        }
    }
}else{

}
```

i just try like this but not work

```
if(!preg_match("/\.\,|'/",$value)){
  blablabla
}else{
  blablabla
}
```

because I am still learning php so confused what to do, thank you if anyone would like to help

Comment: an example of what you want ot match would be helpful

Comment: ok i will edit for complete sample, just need to bypass from explode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to match a list of characters, use the character class `[]` instead like:

```
if(!preg_match("/[.,']/",$value)){
  blablabla
}else{
  blablabla
}
```

Learning regex is invaluable, read up on it and it'll pay for itself in a month!

Comment: and how to put space? just like this preg_match("/[.,'\s]/",$value)